# JSON object in JSON object in React-Native

Tags: json, react-native

I have a function that gave me this JSON back:

```
{
   "ImageWidth":3000,
   "ImageHeight":2002,
   "Orientation":1,
   "originalUri":"IMG_0005.JPG",
   "exif":{
      "{TIFF}":{
         "Model":"NIKON D800E",
         "ResolutionUnit":2,
         "Software":"Aperture 3.4.5",
         "Artist":"Nicolas Cornet",
         "DateTime":"2012:08:08 14:55:30",
         "XResolution":72,
         "Orientation":1,
         "Copyright":"Nicolas Cornet",
         "Make":"NIKON CORPORATION",
         "YResolution":72
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can access the {TIFF} in React-Native (TypeScript)?

`Json.exif.TIFF` doesn't work!

What function have these braces/ curly brackets around TIFF? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use brackets to put a string literal/variable to access the json values

```js
let data = {"ImageWidth":3000,"ImageHeight":2002,"Orientation":1,"originalUri":"IMG_0005.JPG","exif":{"{TIFF}":{"Model":"NIKON D800E","ResolutionUnit":2,"Software":"Aperture 3.4.5","Artist":"Nicolas Cornet","DateTime":"2012:08:08 14:55:30","XResolution":72,"Orientation":1,"Copyright":"Nicolas Cornet","Make":"NIKON CORPORATION","YResolution":72}}}

console.log(data.exif["{TIFF}"])
```